# prove that (f: ℕ-->ℕ is strictly increasing) ⇒ ∀(x ∈ ℕ)[ x <= f(x)]

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

My math prof used this result in a proof about sequences without justification. I tried to prove it myself (as an exercise), but my proof quickly got out of control. I ended up using set cardinality and the injectivity of strictly increasing functions. My (unfinished) proof also depends on the truth value of [|A| > |B|] ⇒ A ⊈ B, which I think will be even harder to prove (if it is not axiomatic). Is there a more obvious way to prove this result? I feel like there must be because my prof stated it without explaining.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try by induction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By induction: $0 \leq f(0)$ is ok.

Then if $n\leq f(n) \Rightarrow n+1 \leq f(n)+1 \leq f(n+1)$ because $f$ is strictly increasing.

The last "$\leq$" is because $f(n) < f(n+1) \Rightarrow f(n)+1 \leq f(n+1)$.

Comment: Wow, yes! Thank you. I feel a bit dumb lol.

Comment: How do you know that $0\leq f(0)$? Couldn't the function be strictly increasing and be less than $0$ at $f(0)$? For example, $f(x)=x-3$ is strictly increasing and $f(0)=-3$.

Comment: @Axion004 It's given that $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by Mathematical induction is straight forward.

$$f(1)\ge 1$$ by the definition of $f(n)\in \mathbb{N}$

If $f(n)\ge n$ then $f(n+1)>f(n)\ge n$ thus $f(n+1)\ge n+1$

That proves the desired result.